# Replacing text in <body>

Tags: javascript, html

I m new to javascript and would be great if you could help me with this issue I m facing.
In the HTML code below, I m trying to highlight a particular word(say "message")by replacing the word by appending  to it to make it bold.

```
<body>
  <img src="http://some.web.site/image.jpg" title="abcd" />
  This is a test message.
</body>
```

The String "This is a test message" is found directly in the body element(so there is no id, and hence no getElementById can be used to extract the text).

So I got the entire body element and extracted the text by using textContent.(this gave me the text and ignored the image that is above the text in the html.)
Then after highlighting the word I set the 'body's textContent back to the new String.

The problem is that now I m not able to preserve the image that was above the text, and the new body has only the value of the textContent in it, and the image is lost. This is the JS I used(but now I m replacing message with the word phone).

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent;
  var v = x.replace("message","phone");
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent = v;
} 
</script>
```

Is there any other way to replace text that is placed directly under the body, which has other elements too?

Comment: Y U NO using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?

Comment: Because [jQuery sucks](http://adamhaskell.net/img/jquery.png)?

Comment: @Kolink jQuery doesn't suck if you use it correctly, like the image implies. If you use the full functionality it's a great tool. Otherwise vanilla JS will be faster, smoother and easier, yes. But for large projects with alot of javascript, jQuery is a great way to reduce the time you need to work on the project.

Comment: @Rune I agree with what you're saying, but in my opinion, even if used right, it's an unwieldly monster of a tool.

Comment: @Kolink I must agree that it is massive, with lots of things you may use in one project, but not in the other. But the impact on the speed isn't too large if not used too much. It's ideal for creating things like an interactive menu, because of all the sliding functions etc. If you use vanilla JS, you need to reinvent half the wheel for the correct animation, thus losing time. And often with developing websites, time is money. You can't say that the website gets visibly slower just because of jQuery itself. It might be because of what you do with it and how you do it. Wow, charlimit :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do something like this, you would need to loop through all text nodes in the document, search for the word, and wrap it.

Something like this:

```
function highlight(str,node) {
    if( !node) node = document.body;
    var c = node.children, l = c.length, i, p;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if( c[i].nodeType == 1) highlight(str,c[i]);
        if( c[i].nodeType == 3) {
            if( (p=c[i].data.indexOf(str)) > -1) {
                c[i].splitText(p);
                c[i].nextSibling.deleteData(0,str.length);
                c[i].parentNode.insertBefore(
                    document.createElement('b'),c[i].nextSibling
                ).appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should do it. To use, just call `highlight("message")`, with whatever text you want. Note that this will be case-sensitive - if you need caseless matching, let me know and I'll edit to take that into account (although for the most part you could probably get away with `highlight("message"); highlight("Message");`)

Also, you can limit the search to a particular element. Let's say you have `<div id="replace-me">`, you can limit the search to that element like so:

```
highlight("message",document.getElementById('replace-me'));
```

(You can use any way to get the node, this is just the easiest)

Answer (score 0):

The textContent property sets or returns the textual content of the specified node, and all its descendants.

If you set the textContent proerty, any child nodes are removed and replaced by a single Text node containing the specified string.

refer to [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var children = document.body.childNodes;
for(var len = children.length, child=0; child<len; child++){
    if (children[child].nodeType === 3){ // textnode
        var contents = children[child].nodeValue;
       children[child].nodeValue = contents.replace(/message/gi, 'phone');
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works for top-level nodes. While this is the case in the particular example given in the question, it won't work if there's even one containing element.

Comment: @Kolink, i know. I am answering to the final "*Is there any other way to replace text that is placed directly under the body*"