# Bold text in body using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, highlight

This code is attempting to highlight (by adding 'bold' tag) some characters that are in the HTML body. (These are specified in the JS function)
But instead of the text becoming bold, I get the 'bold' tag as the result in the html page that is getting rendered.

While I want some thing like

This is a test **message**

I get

```
This is a test <b>message</>
```

Any help would be awesome.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<script>

function myFunction(){
        var children = document.body.childNodes;
    for(var len = children.length, child=0; child<len; child++){
     if (children[child].nodeType === 3){ // textnode
        var highLight = new Array('abcd', 'edge', 'rss feeds');
        var contents = children[child].nodeValue;
        var output = contents;
        for(var i =0;i<highLight.length;i++){
            output = delimiter(output, highLight[i]); 
        }


    children[child].nodeValue= output; 
    }
    }
}

function delimiter(input, value) {
    return unescape(input.replace(new RegExp('(\\b)(' + value + ')(\\b)','ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3'));
}
</script>



</head>
<body>
<img src="http://some.web.site/image.jpg" title="abcd"/>

These words are highlighted: knorex, edge, rss feeds while these words are not: knewedge, abcdef, rss feedssss

<input type ="button" value="Button" onclick = "myFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about cases like `<i>rss</i> feeds`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing text in <body>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438198/replacing-text-in-body)

Comment: This is a duplicate of the poster’s question from yesterday, though possibly better formulated.

Comment: Or maybe rather a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456079/function-to-make-html-text-bold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are putting HTML in to a text node, so it is being evaluated strictly as text. One easy fix would be to simply operate on the innerHTML of the body element, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<script>

function myFunction(){
  var highLight = ['abcd', 'edge', 'rss feeds'],
      contents = document.body.innerHTML;

  for( i = 0; i < highLight.length; i++ ){
    contents = delimiter(contents, highLight[i]); 
  }

  document.body.innerHTML = contents;
}

function delimiter(input, value) {
  return input.replace(new RegExp('(\\b)(' + value + ')(\\b)','ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
}
</script>



</head>
<body>
<img src="http://some.web.site/image.jpg" title="abcd"/>

These words are highlighted: knorex, edge, rss feeds while these words are not: knewedge, abcdef, rss feedssss

<input type ="button" value="Button" onclick = "myFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A textNode cannot have child elements so it needs to be replaced, one way;

Replace

```
children[child].nodeValue = output;
```

With

```
var n = document.createElement("span");
n.innerHTML = output;
children[child].parentNode.replaceChild(n, children[child]);
```